# Can I get duplicate results (from one table) in an INTERSECT operation between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, intersect

I know the wording of the question is awkward, but I couldn't phrase it any better. Let me explain the situation.

There's table `A` which has a bunch of columns (`a`, `b`, `c` ... ) and I run a `SELECT` query on it like so:

`SELECT a FROM A WHERE b IN ('....')` (*the ellipsis indicates a number of values to be matched to*)

There's another table `B` which has a bunch of columns (`d`, `e`, `f` ... ) and I run a `SELECT` query on it like so:

`SELECT d FROM B WHERE f = '...'` (*the ellipsis indicates a single value to be matched to*)

Now I should say here that the two tables store different types of information about the same entity, but the columns `a` and `d` contain the exact same data (in this case, an ID). I want to find out the intersection of the two tables so I run this:

`SELECT a FROM A WHERE b IN ('....') INTERSECT SELECT d FROM B WHERE f = '...'`

Now here's the problem:

The first `SELECT` contains a set of values in the `WHERE` clause, right? So let's say the set is (`1234`, `2345`,`3456`). Now, the result of this query when `b` is matched ONLY to `1234` is, let's say, `abc`. When it's matched to `2345`, it's `def`, suppose. And matching to `3456`, it gives `abc`.

Let's suppose these two results (`abc` and `def`) are also in the set of results from the second `SELECT`.

So, now, putting back the entire set of values to matched into the `WHERE` clause, the `INTERSECT` operation will give me `abc` and `def`. But I want `abc` twice since two values in the `WHERE` clause set match to the second `SELECT`.

Is there any way I can get that?

I hope it's not too complicated to understand my problem. This is a real-life problem I'm facing in my job.

## Data structure and my code

Table `A` contains general information about a company:

```
company_id | branch_id | no_of_employees | city
```

Table `B` contains the financials of the company:

```
company_id | branch_id | revenue | profits
```

**First SELECT**:

`SELECT branch_id FROM A WHERE CITY IN ('Dallas', 'Miami', 'New Orleans')`

Now, running each city separately in the first `SELECT`, I get the `branch_id`s:

```
 branch_id | city   
        23 | Dallas 
        45 | Miami
        45 | New Orleans
```

Once again, this seems impractical as to how two cities can have the same branch ids, but please bear with me on this.

**Second SELECT**:

```
SELECT branch_id FROM B
WHERE REVENUE = 5000000
```

I know this is a little impractical, but for the purpose of this example, it suffices.

Running this query I get the following set:

```
11
23
45
22
10
```

So the `INTERSECT` will give me just `23` and `45`. But I want `45` twice, since both Miami and New Orleans have that `branch_id` and that `branch_id` has generated a revenue of 5 million.

Comment: Probably easier to dissect if you could provide a sample data set. You explained it thoroughly but everyone will have to create the data set according to your explanation. This will ensure we don't mess up your data, though it's test data

Comment: Dude, don't describe datasets in words like _"here is the value A then another value B and finally value C"_. It's `(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from Microsoft's documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)
:
**"INTERSECT returns distinct rows that are output by both the left and right input queries operator."**

So NO, it is not possible to get the same value twice when using `INTERSECT` because the results will be `DISTINCT`.  However if you build an `INNER JOIN` correctly you can do essentially the same thing as `INTERSECT` except keep the repetitive results by NOT using `distinct` or `group by`.

```
SELECT
   A.a
FROM
   A
   INNER JOIN B
   ON A.a = B.d
   AND B.F = '....'
WHERE b IN ('....')
```

And for your specific Example that you edited:

```
SELECT
   branch_id
FROM
   A
   INNER JOIN B
   ON A.branch_id = B.branch_id
   AND B.REVENUE = 5000000
WHERE A.CITY IN ('Dallas', 'Miami', 'New Orleans')
```

Answer (score 3):

You overcomplicated your task a lot:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE CITY IN (...)
  AND EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM B
      WHERE B.REVENUE = 5000000
        AND B.branch_id = A.branch_id
    )
```

`INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` are both returning row sets with `DISTINCT` applied.
Regular joining/filtering operations are not performed by `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`.